# Imtrying to read a CSV with pandas but keep getting FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
baby_names = pd.read_csv("us_baby_names.csv")
```

both the py file and csv are stored in the same project folder on my desktop and I've tried copy and pasting the title of the CSV into my editor to make sure it's exact but had no luck.

The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File us_baby_names.csv does not exist: 'us_baby_names.csv'
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshot of the error doesn't add anything. You should include the traceback and the errors in most cases.

Comment: Check the working directory of your IDE.  Might be pointing somewhere else.

Comment: I lied, the screenshot shows you're in the wrong directory. I'll reverse my removal

Comment: Working directory is different than the csv file.Try proper relative path

Comment: You can try to give the absolute path. It is generally better in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the directory of the python file being executed and join it with your csv filename:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
baby_names = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "us_baby_names.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The python-file and csv-file doesnt seem to be in the same project folder.

Temp.py path:

```
/Users/simeonnsubuga/.spyder-py3/temp.py
```

us_baby_names.csv path:

```
/ProjectOne/us_baby_names.csv
```

Your script cant find the csv-file as it is not on the same path as the script. You need to either put the script and csv in the same folder, or put the full path to the csv-file in your script.